# Airflow triggering the "on_failure_callback" when the "dagrun_timeout" is exceeded

Tags: airflow, alert, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer

Currently working on setting up alerts for long running tasks in Airflow. To cancel/fail the airflow dag I've put "dagrun_timeout" in the default_args, and it does what I need, fails/errors the dag when its been running for too long (usually stuck). The only problem is that the function in "on_failure_callback" doesn't get called when the dagrun_timeout is exceeded, because the "on_failure_callback" is on the task level (I think) while the dagrun_timeout is on the dag level.

How can I execute the "on_failure_callback" when the dagrun_timeout is exceeded, or how can I specify a function to be called when a dag fails? Or should I re-think my approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting `on_failure_callback` during DAG declaration:

```py
with DAG(
    dag_id="failure_callback_example",
    on_failure_callback=_on_dag_run_fail,
    ...
) as dag:
...
```

The explanation is that `on_failure_callback` defined in `default_args` will get passed only to the **Tasks** being created and not to the DAG object.

Here is an example to try this behaviour:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import TaskInstance
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator


def _on_dag_run_fail(context):
    print("***DAG failed!! do something***")
    print(f"The DAG failed because: {context['reason']}")
    print(context)


def _alarm(context):
    print("** Alarm Alarm!! **")
    task_instance: TaskInstance = context.get("task_instance")
    print(f"Task Instance: {task_instance} failed!")


default_args = {
    "owner": "mi_empresa",
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "on_failure_callback": _alarm,
}


with DAG(
    dag_id="failure_callback_example",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 9, 7),
    schedule_interval=None,
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
    on_failure_callback=_on_dag_run_fail,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(seconds=45),
) as dag:

    delayed = BashOperator(
        task_id="delayed",
        bash_command='echo "waiting..";sleep 60; echo "Done!!"',
    )
    will_fail = BashOperator(
        task_id="will_fail",
        bash_command="exit 1",
        # on_failure_callback=_alarm,
    )
delayed >> will_fail
```

You can find the logs of the callbacks execution in the Scheduler logs `AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/scheduler/date/failure_callback_example` :

```
[2021-09-24 13:12:34,285] {logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - [2021-09-24 13:12:34,285] {dag.py:862} INFO - Executing dag callback function: <function _on_dag_run_fail at 0x7f83102e8670>
[2021-09-24 13:12:34,336] {logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - ***DAG failed!! do something***
[2021-09-24 13:12:34,345] {logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - The DAG failed because: timed_out
```

#### Edit:

Within the `context` dict the key `reason` is passed in order to specify the cause of the DAG run failure. Some values are: `'reason': 'timed_out'` or `'reason': 'task_failure'` . This could be use to perfom specific behaviour in the callback based on the `reason` of the DAG Run failure.

Comment: One issue with this solution is that the _on_dag_run_fail will get called if one of the tasks fails in the DAG (which will consequently fail the DAG), I would need to only trigger the DAG level callback when it is timed out.

Comment: Hey @Anton, I'm not sure If I'm following you.  The DAG `on_failure_callback` will get called when the DAG run fails, dosn't matter why. If you want to know the reason of the failure, and act accordingly, you could access the key `reason` passed in the context dict. I'll add this to my answer above.

Comment: Hello @NicoE - This is what I also had in mind, but based on what is explained in the documentation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.1/logging-monitoring/callbacks.html#example) it appears it does not work like that.

Comment: Can you, explain better why on_failure_callback defined in default_args applies only for tasks and not for the DAG object, please? For me it don't make any sense
@NicoE